Using Databricks asset bundles with typer instead of argparse
I want to use Databricks asset bundles - I'd like to use typer as a CLI tool, but I have only been able to set it up with argparse. Argparse seems to be able to retrieve the arguments from the databricks task, but not typer.
I specified two entrypoints in my pyproject.toml
[tool.poetry.scripts]
mypackage_ep_typer = "my_package.entrypoint_typer:main"
mypackage_ep_argparse = "my_package.entrypoint_argparse:entrypoint_generic"

I'm able to use the asset bundles with an entrypoint to my ELTL applications with argparse as follows in the entrypoint_argparse.py:
def entrypoint_generic():
    """Execute the application."""
    logger.info("Executing 'argparse' entrypoint...")
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="My module.")
    parser.add_argument(
        "--applicationname",
        help="The name of the application to execute.",
        type=str,
        required=True,
        dest="applicationname",
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()
    logger.info(f"{args.applicationname=}")

This one deploys and runs without any issues in the asset bundle's workflow task.
However, if I try the same with typer in entrypoint_typer.py, I cannot get it to work:
def main(
    applicationname: Annotated[str, typer.Option(help="Application to execute.")]
):
    """Execute the application."""
    logger.info("Executing 'typer' entrypoint...")
    logger.info(f"{applicationname=}")

I can run typer locally:
> poetry run python -m typer .\entrypoint_typer.py run --applicationname MYAPPNAME
2024-11-06 xx:xx:xx - root - INFO - Executing 'typer' entrypoint...
2024-11-06 xx:xx:xx - root - INFO - applicationname='MYAPPNAME'

But when I try to deploy and run my asset bundle, I get this error when the workflow task tries to start:
TypeError: main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'applicationname'


